# How to fix changing css to buttons after being clicked on

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to make a code so that a button will change color and will not be able to be clicked on again after it is clicked on once. The code does all that except it changes all three of the buttons I want it to affect when you click on just one button.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick(event) {
  event.className = "button visited";
  if (clicks >= 2) {
    alert("WRONG! YOU LOSE! TRY AGAIN!");
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
  }
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 10px dashed white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.visited {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
  border: 10px dashed black;
  color: black;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.button:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  border: 10px dashed black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this)">Button1</button>

<button id="button2" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this)">Button2</button>

<button id="button3" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this)">Button3</button>
```

I want to be able to click on one of the buttons and only that button will change colors and not be able to be clicked on instead of all of the buttons changing when one button is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the button un-clickable, you simply need to disable it. So you need to pass the element's id as shown here.

```
<button id="button1" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button1</button>
<button id="button2" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button2</button>
<button id="button3" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button3</button>
```

Then you simply define the method using the `.disabled` function on he button.

```
function disableButton(id){
     document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;  
}
```

Comment: I just one button to be disabled when it is clicked and the function I have to still work. Would your edit still work?

Comment: When you pass the id of the button using`this.id` and disable it, it only makes that one button inactive while the other two will still be active

Comment: I believe you need CSS for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make it so the button is clickable, but when you click it once the button changes color and it not able to be clicked again. The code works, its just that when one button is clicked, all of the buttons change color and are not able to be clicked instead of just that one button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

pass argument this.id rather than this because we want to get the id of clicked button.
so your code of button is...

```
<button id="button1" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button1</button>
<button id="button2" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button2</button>
<button id="button3" class="button" type="button" onclick="onClick(this.id)">Button3</button>
```

and try to your js code in the format I given below.

```
var btn1_click = 0;
var btn2_click = 0;
var btn3_click = 0;

function onClick(clicked_id) {
    var btn_id = clicked_id

    if(btn_id == "button1" && btn1_click == 0)
    {
        btn1_click++ 

        your code 
    }
    else if(btn_id == "button2" && btn2_click == 0) 
    {
        btn2_click++

        your code 
    } 
    else if(btn_id == "button3" && btn3_click == 0) 
    {
        btn3_click++

        your code 
    }
```

And when you reset then you should reset the...

```
btn1_click = 0;
btn2_click = 0;
btn3_click = 0
```